# git push only one folder

Tags: git, web, webserver

Here is my situation:

In my local repo I have a few different folders and up until now I have always just used ftp to upload the contents of one folder to the web server. for example, In my git repo I have a few folders, source, phonegap, cordova and a few others. I upload the contents of the source folder to the webserver folder.

I want to make this workflow more streamlined by using git to push to the webserver. You see the problem already, I only want the contents of my source folder pushed.

I think there could be 2 ways:
1: There is a way in git to push the contents of this folder to the server (unikely)
2: There are other ways around this problem by using black magic to make the user think they are on website.com/app but it gets its files from website.com/appsource/source

Do you guys have a solution?

Comment: you could try pushing the folder to your git repo, and then pulling the files again from your server. Write a startup script for your server which makes it pull the newest version every time you restart, to make it somewhat auto updating

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this.

You could set your web server to map any given URL to any given filesystem path, as you suggest in your second option.  How you do this depends on what web server software you're using, so you would consult your web server docs or, if you can't find an answer there, post a question tagged with the specific web server software asking how to configure its URL mappings.

You might be able to solve the problem at the filesystem level instead, by pushing to a repo at one path and creating a symbolic link or shortcut (depending on OS / filesystem) pointing your web server content root to the `source/` directory.  Again, consult docs for your OS/fs or post a question with the relevant info and tags.

Since you've posted it as a git question: the most direct git-based solution (but not really one I would particularly recommend) would be to set up a post-receive hook that copies the files to the web server after each push.  If for some reason you choose this over simpler non-git-based solutions, you can read up on git hooks here: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Not that I recommend either of these here, but for the record: Note that while you can't just push a subdirectory to the server, there are two ways you can get a similar effect. You could split the source directory into its own repo, then include it in the parent repo as a submodule (but there are some costs and complexities there) - and then you could push just the source repo.  Or, you could use sparse checkout to only update the one folder of the work tree - but this doesn't address the fact that the checked-out files would appear in a directory named `.../source/`.

In any event, the problem you present has much easier solutions if you address it as a server setup issue instead of a git issue.

Comment: Thanks alot! We actually dont host the site ourselfs, the company is way to small for that. Instead we use a web hosting service, and I dont know what kind of options we have to do things like file system links and such.

After looking some more into git automation, and things like production servers I can conclude that that is the best option, although I am not sure if we will ever have such a system set up, so for now its going to be a manual task.

Thanks for your elaborate comment and effort, I appriciate it!